# autorestart a python file only after it raises error

Tags: python, error-handling

i am using python for web crawling and i have a program which i want to be run forever.
unfortunately i may run into errors at any time.
for example:

```
import schedule
import time
import threading

def test():
    print('test')

    #here is the main code which may cause any error anytime

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(test)


def running():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
thread = threading.Thread(target=running)
thread.start()

    #rest of the program which may cause any error anytime
```

how can i modify it that anytime an error occurred it restart itself from the beginning?
i used `while` , `try` but couldn't get an answer and also read about `os` , `subprocess` but again nothing useful.

Comment: use `try/except` to catch error and then you can go to beginning  of `while True`  or you can exit `while True` which may be in external `while True` with functions which reset settings before you run code again. On Linux it is popular to use external program [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to control process and restart it when it doesn't work. Eventually you run it periodically using program `cron` instead of module `sheduler` - and it will run it again afer minute(s) even if it crushed.

Comment: the problem with `while True` is that it will run the program over and over even if it does not raise an error.and if you make a statement to break the while when the program does not raise error,the program will run only once and won't restart after an error(consider that program is a time based one and can raise error at any time...)